# Div inside of an another div like a TV screen

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm making a page that shows some website samples using wordpress. Basically I have a div with a background image of a mobile screen and inside of that I have another div that grabs the uploaded image from a field I created in my cusotm taxonomy  post. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php if( get_field('tablet_image') ): ?>
    <div class="tablet-screen">
        <div class="inside-screen">
            <img src="<? the_field('tablet_image'); ?>" height="1027" width="768" class="img-responsive">
            <p><? the_field('tablet_image'); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works perfect and displays both the tablet screen and the picture.

However the CSS part is where I need help here is what I have so far:

```
.tablet-screen {
    background-image: url(../img/tablet-screen.png);
    position: absolute;
    height: 1080px;
    width: 812px;
}

.inside-screen {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1027px;
    width: 768px;
}
```

What kind of styling would I need to add to make this work?

You can view one of the pages for reference here:

[MY SITE](http://gm2016.demosite.us/projects/harvard-international-review/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
.tablet-screen {
    background:transparent url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/IPad_3.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 812px 1080px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 1080px;
    width: 812px;
}

.inside-screen {
    position: relative;
    left: 97px;
    top:100px;
    height: 880px;
    width: 618px;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tablet-screen"><div class="inside-screen"></div></div>
```

Note: Adjust your needs

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/1p4bhs3w/5/)**

Comment: Thank you, this really helped, wish there was a way to make this responsive!

Comment: I made a update for the scroll inside the tablet... for responsive you can use media queries and readjust your sizes depending on the show device (phone, table, desktop, etcc...)

Comment: I don't know if that really helped, take a look at my site again I did the changes you told me too. I need to work on changing some of the numbers you gave me, but its a great start thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something like this:

```
.inside-screen {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1027px;
    width: 768px;
    left: 38px;
    top: 41px;
}
```

But I think the width and height from your .tablet-screen is different from the width/height of your image.

Answer (score 0):

This is as responsive as I could get it. (You can adjust it with media queries for example).

Note that the dimensions aren't perfect yet, but you can adjust this quite easily. (You could measure and calculate the exact percentages with a software like Adobe Photoshop). The top and bottom margin should be identical, just like the left and right margin (of the unused content - the tablet border, shadow, etc.).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tablet-screen">
  <div class="tablet-screen">
    <img class="tablet-image" src="http://gm2016.demosite.us/wp-content/themes/roots/assets/img/tablet-screen.png" />
    <div class="tablet-image-inside">
      <img src="http://gm2016.demosite.us/media/Godfather-Films-Desktop.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tablet-screen {
  width:100%;
  max-width:843px;
  position:relative;
}

.tablet-image {
  width:100%;
}

.tablet-image-inside {
  position: absolute;
  width: 93%; // percentage of used width (within the tablet screen)
  height:93%; // percentage of used height (within the tablet screen)
  left: 3.5%; // percentage of unused width (the outside of the table screen)
  top: 3.5%; // percentage of unused height (the outside of the tablet)
  overflow:auto;
}

.tablet-image-inside img {
  width:100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qgohpo3/)